# Refresh Data Table Without Reloading The Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use this Flask code to manually display SQLAlchemy Data:

```
@portfolioPath.route('/portfolio', methods=['GET','POST'])
def portfolio():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        all_data = HoldingsTable.query.all()
        return render_template("portfolio.html", all_data_html = all_data)
```

in this dynamic HTML table that shows the queried data here:

```
<!-- Equity Holdings Overview Table -->
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Trade Date</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Symbol</th>
    <th>Shares</th>
    <th>Purchase Price</th>
  </tr>
  {% for row in all_data_html %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.date_purchase}}</td>      
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.ticker}}</td>
    <td>{{row.shares}}</td>
    <td> &#x24; {{row.price_purchase}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

with this refresh button that manually displays or refreshes the data table, but the inconvenience is that it reloads the whole page with it:

```
<form action="{{url_for('core.portfolio')}}" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-md-2 col align-self-end">
          <button class="btn btn-primary float-end" type="submit" style="margin:5px;">1. Refresh!</button>             
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So, I tried to add Ajax/jQuery to load the data in the table without reloading the overall each time. So, I tested with this small code in the same files:

```
  <h3>What's 1 + 1?</h3>
  <form>
    <input type=text size=5 name=proglang>
    <a href=# id=process_input><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
  </form>
<p id=result></p>
```

of course, the python function is as follow:

```
@portfolioPath.route('/background_process')
def background_process():
    try:
        lang = request.args.get('proglang', 0, type=str)
        if lang.lower() == '2':
            return jsonify(result='You are wise')
        else:
            return jsonify(result='Really?')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

and the jQuery script looks like this:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/background_process', {
      proglang: $('input[name="proglang"]').val(),
    }, function(data) {
      $("#result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

So, I did try to change the script to reload just the table:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('a#wallet_refresh_id').bind('click', function() {
    $.getJSON('/wallet_refresh', function(all_data_html) {
      $("#table").html(all_data_html);
    });
    return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

with the linked flask back-end part:

```
@portfolioPath.route('/wallet_refresh', methods=['POST'])
def wallet_refresh():
    if request.method == "POST":
        all_data = HoldingsTable.query.all()
        return render_template("portfolio.html",
                                all_data_html = all_data
                                )
    return render_template("portfolio.html")
```

and a new submit button:

```
<form id="wallet_table_form">
<h3>REFRESH THE DATABASE</h3>
<form>
  <a href=wallet_refresh id=wallet_refresh_id><button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

But clearly, I'm mixing things up here because nothing happens, what's the catch, please?

Comment: Take a look at [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

made it work thanks! Had to create a new route for it

Answer (score 0):

You have to do too many fixes to get it work.

1. in html, if you are using ajax you don't need form tags.
2. you don't need to use anchor tag. you can use a button and use click event on it.
3. I don't know which element has id `table`. For updating you need data you need to give id to tr tag in table. and maniplate it using js.

```html
<h3>REFRESH THE DATABASE</h3>
<button id="wallet_refresh_id" class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>[your headings]</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="data_holder"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in javascript now you don't need to return false and can use #wallet_refresh_id and use a for loop.

```js
$('#wallet_refresh_id').bind('click', function() {
  $.getJSON('/wallet_refresh', function(all_data_html) {
     for (var i of all_data_html.data ){ // using .data, we will return json in flask 
     $("#data_holder").append(`<td>${i.id}</td><td>${i.date_purchase}</td><td>${i.name}</td>`[...so on write the other])
     } 
  });
});
```

in python code, you should use `get` method rather `post` as you are using get in ajax. and you need to return the data only not the rendered template. You need to use json.dumps.

```
@portfolioPath.route('/wallet_refresh', methods=['GET'])
def wallet_refresh():
    if request.method == "GET":
        all_data = HoldingsTable.query.all()
        return json.dumps({"data":all_data })
                                
    return render_template("portfolio.html")
```

Comment: ok I updated everything but it throw an error: `TypeError: Object of type HoldingsTable is not JSON serializable` working on fixing it

Comment: ok I think I can close this one because it works, just the serialization error is another step forward, and will open a new question for it to not dilute this one, thank you again!